# BuddyPress user bio in profile

Tags: buddypress, profiles

I am trying to figure out how to have a user bio in the user profile using BuddyPress.

For example, on this page http://buddypress.org/community/members/johnjamesjacoby/activity/just-me/ where it says "I help lead the BuddyPress and bbPress projects. I also like puppies, potato chips, and a good nap."

I'm assuming it's default behavior since it's on the BuddyPress site, but if it's not, that might be why I'm having issues. Is that a BuddyPress plugin? How can I get that implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a User Bio Profile Field and then displayed it by inserting the following into member-header.php in the BuddyPress theme files:

```
<?php if ( bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=User Bio' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="user-bio"><?php bp_profile_field_data( 'field=User Bio' );?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enable Extended Profiles on the Buddypress > Components page, you can add new questions to the profile form on the Buddypress > Profile Fields page...

See: http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/configure-buddypress-components/